# Updating ng-template from child component

Tags: angular, ng-template, ng-content

I am using ng-template for passing content to Child Component, but I am looking to get specific value of selected item from the child component

I have a grand child component too, the value is emitted from the Grand Child component to Child component and then to Parent component.

Although I can get the selected value, but it renders same value for complete ng-template

For Example : If I click on last div, all of the Selected values becomes "3"

[image]

You can have much better idea checking below stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfvkoj

EDIT : how can I have it render specific selected values ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working as intended.  It renders the same value because you are rendering `{{selected}}` in every iteration of the template, and `selected` is set to whatever most recent value is emitted from `ChildComponent`.  What did you expect it to render?

As an aside, it is a poor pattern to use `@Input` to send data through multiple levels, from parent to child to grand-child.  This quickly becomes difficult to manage.  Even your very small code sample is already difficult to follow.

I suggest instead that you use a shared service, provided at the parent level

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  ...
}
```

You can then inject that service in parent and grand-child, and use the service to keep track of state.